# Why do we need USB OTG (On-The-Go) drives?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I just recently got curious about [USB OTG (On-The-Go)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), and I think I understand what it is, and what it does. But, as far as I can tell, a flash drive could never be a host, only a slave. So, why are there OTG flash drives? For example, a cell phone is already an OTG device, why wouldn't I be able to connect a regular flash drive thorough a non-OTG adapter? or would I? and if I would, what is the benefit of having OTG flash drives?

Comment: Where did you find an "OTG flash drive"? Just curious.

Comment: Local store. It is a Kingston DT microduo

Comment: @AliChen: https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/ultra-dual-usb-drive-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not about the USB stick being a "host" or "client", it is about telling the *other* device it is connected to that it *needs* to be a Host.

They are required because there are some devices that are normally Client devices but are capable of being a Host.

Your phone is an excellent example of this. Until a few years ago your phone was essentially an extension of your computer and was very limited. It didn't really have the smarts to understand a USB memory stick or have a worthwhile reason to do so. It only needed to be a Client device.

But phones have gotten smarter and more complex and people wanted to be able to plug in a USB stick.

This created a problem because now your phone somehow needs to detect whether it needs to be a Client to a computer or a Host to a memory stick.

USB micro sockets have a pin dedicated to allowing the device to detect whether they are supposed to "host" or just be a dumb client.

A cell phone might well be an OTG device, but in order to "cleanly" tell which mode it needs to be in then it needs this signal to tell it without a doubt which mode it should be in.  Without this then the phone will have to guess which mode it should be in, which can be messy, difficult to establish and potentially cause problems.

Comment: I appreciate you great explanation. NOTE FOR OTHER USERS: Please also read @Ignacio Vazques-Abrams answer, as it greatly complements this answer.

Answer (score 3):

A Micro-B connector has 5 pins; 4 are used for normal USB signals and the fifth pin, the ID pin, is for identifying the cable or other device. If this pin is floating then the connection is assumed to be normal USB and the device configures itself as a USB Device. If it is tied directly to USB ground then it is an OTG connection and the device becomes a USB Host.

OTG flash drives simply have the ID pin on their Micro-B connector grounded so that the device they are plugged in to knows that they need to be a Host in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks, you answer, plus the one given by @Mokubai clarify the whole thing perfectly. I wish I could select both as a conjoined answer.

Comment: The question is "why do we need OTG flash drives". These drives are not "OTG", they can't act as a host, they are just USB devices with  a very short version of "captive" (non-detachable) cable with proper connector signature. The question is based on wrong premise, and your detailed answer is misleading (while being technically correct), since it fails to address the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are very mistaken about the "Kingston DT microduo". This is a dual-interface flash drive with USB-A plug, and Type-C plug in parallel.

[image]

Their mentioning of "OTG" only means that the flash drive has its Type-C plug configured as "USB device", by having 5.1k resistor pull-down on CC line. This is the standard Type-C convention, per Type-C specifications.

This CC configuration (5.1k to ground) signals to a more sophisticated dual-role Type-C device/phone that the phone must assume the host role if the Kingston flash is plugged in with Type-C end. This all has nothing to do with flash-drive being as host device, it is never a host, and the CC-pin never changes. So the original premise of this question is wrong, there is no such thing as USB flash storage with OTG function.

Comment: @fixer1234, I think you got the answer quite right. Depending on port power design, the drive would likely spin-off, fail, and start over, and cycle forever. Then variations can occur.